# `term_start` fails to have `-m` option for shell like bash when using the shell path to invoke

Tags: terminal, functions, microsoft-windows, shell, cygwin

I uses `vim 9.1` shipped with `bash 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)` both installed by `git-bash`.

---

`:h terminal-use` says `:term` will start one "terminal emulator" and ran the job.

Then when I ran `/d/msys64/usr/bin/bash -l` in "git-bash", all works fine. But when I run `:call term_start("/d/msys64/usr/bin/bash -l")` it shows one weird sequence of `/usr/bin/bash: line x: $'P\315': command not found` where "x" keeps increasing from 1 up.

Then I ran `:call term_start("/d/msys64/usr/bin/bash -l -v -x")` it shows

```bash
# Set INFOPATH so it includes users' private info if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/info" ]; then
#   INFOPATH="${HOME}/info:${INFOPATH}"
# fi
?
+ $'\320\177\001'
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: $'\320\177\001': command not found
```

The above ending `#fi` is in "~/.bash_profile" for `msys2` which is sourced due to `-l`. But `hexdump ~/.bash_profile -C` shows "fi.|" (`66 69 0a` in hex where `|` means the file ending and [`0a` means newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68696177/21294350)) in the ending without "?". It is weird for such one "?" causing the above `$'P\315': command not found` loop.

---

The above msys2 uses the same version of `bash` and `vim` as git-bash. Maybe the above workflow of using one bash to open one external bash is weird. Although this problem can probably solved by moving all git-bash configs to msys2 since both use the same version of bash and vim. However, since we already met with this weird situation, I want to know the reason for the ending "?".

**Edited**:

After comparing `:call term_start("/d/msys64/usr/bin/bash -v -x -l")` in vim of `git-bash` and vim of `msys2-mingw-w32`. It is due to the `locale` problem and `C.UTF-8` used by git-bash seems not to totally compatible with `en_US.UTF-8` which is used in *some comments* of the scripts used by `msys2-mingw-w32`. But after changing `locale`, `term_start` still can't recongize those characters like the above `\320\177\001` although vim can recognize now. Finally, I removed those commments with `sed`.

However it says about another weird charater error

```bash
�b
+ $'\320b\001'
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: $'\320b\001': command not found
```

Then after the comparasion I added 2 options `-i -m` (This can solve the above weird character problem although I don't know why these 2 options make those charcters disappear) and seemed to found the problem source. `git-bash` auto installed vim will have the following error when `term_start` but not when in the bash for the same command.

```bash
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
...
if [[ $- == *v* ]]; then
...
+++ [[ hivxBH == *v* ]]
```

Q (Edited):

When running the same bash invocation command in `bash` and `term_start` of `vim`, why does `term_start` in vim fail to use `-m` option for bash which is needed for *job control*?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Do you say what does `.` in `fi.|` mean? Sorry for not saying that. I will edit the question. And when I had some time, I reread the log with options `-v -x` and seemed to find the problem source. I will update with the new info.

Comment: It seems like you figured some of it out. I suspect the options matter for whether this is an interactive or login shell. See man bash: this affects what startup files are read.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have read man bash before writing this post. IMHO `-l` will make bash read `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` on my machine. And `-i` is to make "standard  input and error are both *connected to terminals*" which is important for the above situation. And since for one normal shell invocation in vim `term_start`, the above `himBH` seems to be done before invoking `bash` (checked by putting `echo $-` in the top of `/etc/profile` temporarily) and it seems no option to turn off `i` option (checked by running bash with no options).

Comment: And `shopt -u login_shell` doesn't influence the daily usage as the doc says it just sources some files to init. And normally subshell is run with the [interactive, non-login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856) mode. In sum, lacking `m` in the minimal option `himBH` is the problem. And it can't be turned off by `+m` when in the interactive mode. It seems not one question related with `vi` now.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Is it appropriate to mark this question closed and open one new question focusing on the `-m` option in community like Unix StackExchange / Superuser StackExchange? (This one and the above one is edited. I fotgot to @ someone replying.)

Comment: That seems reasonable to me